# cannot run Heroku app from Hartl's Ruby on Rails Tutorial chapt 7

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, heroku

It has been asked many times already, but the previous solutions didn't work for me so far.

I'm a beginner, I'm trying to learn Rails and I'm following the [famous tutorial from Hartl](https://www.railstutorial.org/book/sign_up#cha-sign_up), I'm at chapter 7
[This is the Github page](https://github.com/Salomanuel/Odin_Project-Ruby_on_Rails_Tutorial) of my project so far, and [this is the Heroku app](https://manuel-sample-app.herokuapp.com/)

the Heroku website says:

> Application error
>   An error occurred in the application and your page could not be served. If you are the application owner, check your logs for details.

`$ heroku logs` says:

```
app[api]: Initial release by user my.email@address.com
app[api]: Release v1 created by user my.email@address.com
app[api]: Release v2 created by user my.email@address.com
app[api]: Enable Logplex by user my.email@address.com
app[api]: Release v2 created by user my.email@address.com
app[api]: Starting process with command "rake db:migrate" by user my.email@address.com 
heroku[run.5962]: Awaiting client
heroku[run.5962]: State changed from starting to up
heroku[run.5962]: Starting process with command "rake db:migrate"
heroku[run.5962]: Process exited with status 127
heroku[run.5962]: State changed from up to complete
app[api]: Starting process with command "rails db:migrate" by user my.email@address.com 
heroku[run.3462]: State changed from starting to up
heroku[run.3462]: Awaiting client
heroku[run.3462]: Starting process with command "rails db:migrate"
heroku[run.3462]: State changed from up to complete
heroku[run.3462]: Process exited with status 127
app[api]: Build started by user my.email@address.com
app[api]: Set LANG, RACK_ENV, RAILS_ENV, RAILS_LOG_TO_STDOUT, RAILS_SERVE_STATIC_FILES, SECRET_KEY_BASE config vars by user my.email@address.com 
app[api]: Release v3 created by user my.email@address.com
app[api]: Release v3 created by user my.email@address.com
app[api]: Release v4 created by user my.email@address.com
app[api]: Release v4 created by user my.email@address.com
app[api]: Attach DATABASE (@ref:postgresql-clear-76865) by user my.email@address.com
app[api]: Deploy ec2b24d by user my.email@address.com
app[api]: Scaled to console@0:Free rake@0:Free web@1:Free worker@0:Free by user my.email@address.com 
app[api]: Release v5 created by user my.email@address.com
app[api]: Release v5 created by user my.email@address.com
app[api]: Build succeeded
heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command "bundle exec pume -C config/puma.rb" 
app[web.1]: bundler: command not found: pume
app[web.1]: Install missing gem executables with "bundle install"
heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
heroku[web.1]: State changed from crashed to starting
heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 127
heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command "bundle exec pume -C config/puma.rb" 
app[web.1]: bundler: command not found: pume
app[web.1]: Install missing gem executables with "bundle install"
heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 127
heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
app[api]: Starting process with command "bundle exec rake db:migrate" by user my.email@address.com  
heroku[run.7856]: Awaiting client
heroku[run.7856]: Starting process with command "bundle exec rake db:migrate"  
heroku[run.7856]: State changed from starting to up
heroku[run.7856]: Process exited with status 0
heroku[run.7856]: State changed from up to complete
heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=infinite-thicket-26445.herokuapp.com request_id=c026b5fa-c5fd-49da-8117-8a237a54926a fwd="83.42.129.78" dyno= connect= service= status=503
heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=infinite-thicket-26445.herokuapp.com request_id=b7fc3150-d64f-4496-b2c9-0e010eeed3b9 fwd="83.42.129.78" dyno= connect= service= status=503
heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=infinite-thicket-26445.herokuapp.com request_id=8ed0ddde-7128-4efb-bf31-670c32129e8c fwd="83.42.129.78" dyno= connect= service= status=503
```

- I have tried to do the migrations (both `$ heroku run rails db:migrate` and `$ heroku run rake db:migrate`)
- I have tried restarting the Heroku dyno (`$ heroku restart`)
- The app works locally brilliantly (on `:development`) and all the test from the book are in the green.
- Output from `$ heroku ps`:
  `=== web (Free): bundle exec pume -C config/puma.rb (1)
   web.1: crashed 2017/04/17 16:21:13 +0200 (~ 2h ago)`
- `$ bundle update` has been run many times, as well as deleting `Gemfile.lock` to rebuild it again
- `.Procfile` is, as suggested in the tutorial:
  `web: bundle exec puma -C config/puma.rb`

and, this is weird:

- in `$ heroku logs` I've noticed this:
  `heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command bundle exec pume -C config/puma.rb`
  `app[web.1]: bundler: command not found: pume`

WHY `pume`? In the `.Procfile` it doesn't say that!

edit2: after it started working, I renamed the app. Now is `https://manuel-sample-app.herokuapp.com/`

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please read "[ask]" and "[mcve]" and their linked pages. Links to your code are not useful or desirable. Instead, reduce your code to the bare minimum to duplicate the problem you're having, and insert it into the question itself. Links rot then break, and at that point make the question turn into nonsense.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, that was stupid..

Turns out that the tutorial says

> The Procfile should be created in your application’s root directory
>
> Listing 7.38: Defining a Procfile for Puma.
>   `./Procfile`
>   `web: bundle exec puma -C config/puma.rb`

and I confused it with `./.Procfile`, so my real Procfile had a typo but I was fixing an useless hidden file with the same name thinking it was the right one
sorry, got too tired today and my eyes were crossing each other

Comment: Also, your logs show: `heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command "bundle exec pume -C config/puma.rb"` and `app[web.1]: bundler: command not found: pume`. The name of the process is `puma` as you stated on your answer.